# astro shikiji transformers not being applied on mdx content

Tags: configuration, astrojs

I am trying to add `shikiji-transformers` to my astro project. Whatever I try to do I can not get [the example](https://shikiji.netlify.app/packages/transformers#transformernotationhighlight) to work.

```
export function foo() {
  console.log('Highlighted') // [!code highlight]
}
```

I have to following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/mdx": "^2.1.1",
    "astro": "^4.4.0",
    "astro-compress": "^2.2.10",
    "shikiji-transformers": "^0.10.2",
  }
```

And the following config:

```
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import mdx from "@astrojs/mdx";
import * as transformers from 'shikiji-transformers';

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  site: "https://www.sanderboer.nl/",
  prefetch: true,
  markdown: {
    syntaxHighlight: "shiki",
    shikiConfig: {
      // https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#shiki-configuration
      // https://shikiji.netlify.app/packages/transformers
      transformers: Object.values(transformers)
    },
  },
  integrations: [
    mdx(),
  ],
});
```

I ue the configuration as [described in the astro documentation](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#shiki-configuration) but no luck.

In the rendered output I get

[image: output of code]

Comment: not sure I understand. the rendered output screenshot you posted _is_ syntax-highlighted?

Comment: it is, but the line `console.log('Highlighted')` is not highlighted as it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the transformer you found in the documentation and pass it to the config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import { transformerNotationHighlight } from 'shikiji-transformers';

export default defineConfig({
  markdown: {
    syntaxHighlight: "shiki",
    shikiConfig: {
      // https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#shiki-configuration
      // https://shikiji.netlify.app/packages/transformers
      transformers: [
        transformerNotationHighlight()
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I read the documentation wrong and I needed to still call the transformer instead of "simply" passing them in the array